# IE 11 - Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'xxx' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

I am using angular 1.3 and below is my code

```
'use strict';

angular.module('App').controller('testController', TestController);

TestController.$inject = ['a1Service', '$scope', '$window'];

function TestController(a1Service, $scope, $window) {

}
```

It's working perfectly fine in chrome and firefox, But not working in IE 11. can someone please take a look and suggest what's wrong with IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'xxx' is not
> registered

This error occurs when the $controller() service is called with a string that does not match any of the registered controllers.

Please check the `ng-controller` directive attribute, make sure it doesn't contain the type error. And, compare the `ng-controller` attribute value with the registered controller name, make sure it doesn't contain the typo error. More detail information about the "ctrlreg" error, please check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg).

Besides, you could try to refer to the following sample, it works well on my side (using IE browser).

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">    
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
            </li>
        </ul>    
    </div>    
    <script src="namesController.js"></script>
</body>
```

Code in the namesController.js:

```
var TestController = function(alservice, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.names = [
        { name: 'Jani', country: 'Norway' },
        { name: 'Hege', country: 'Sweden' },
        { name: 'Kai', country: 'Denmark' }
    ];
}   

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('alservice', function () {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
TestController.$inject = ['alservice', '$scope', '$window'];
app.controller('namesCtrl', TestController);
```

The output:

[image]

If still not working, try to clear the IE browser cache and re-check it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, but somehow it works when I change the controller declaration like:

```
'use strict';

lanyonApp.controller('selfNomineeController', ['nominationService', '$scope', '$window',

    function (nominationService, $scope, $window) {
   
    }
]);
```

I am still wondering why it was failing but yes for IE 11 you can't say so much. thanks